# Set the value to input field using children()

Tags: jquery

I need to set the input value using the following way

```
<table width="50%" border="0" id="pls-batting">
    <tr id="1">
        <td>
            <input name="in" type="text" value="5">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
        <td>
            <input name="in" type="text" value="">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

value = $("table#pls-batting tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1)").children().val();
```

When I alert the value it returns '5'. It is well and good. Similarly I need to set the value to input field for the 2nd row.   I use the following code

```
$("table#pls-batting tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1)").children().val='test';
```

But it is not working. Is there any way to set the value using the `children()` method or by using row ID?

Comment: to set a value you use `.val('test')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this...

```
$("table#pls-batting tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1)").children().val('test');
```

or you can try some other way

```
$("table#pls-batting tr:eq(1) td:eq(0)").children().val('test');
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.val()` function is overloaded. If you simply call `.val()`, you will get the value of the `input` control. Where as if you pass some parameter to like `.val("test")`, jQuery will try to set the value for that `input`.

Read more about `.val()` on [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Hope fully you got the concept.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
$("table#pls-batting tr:nth-child(2) input").val('test');
```